# grape ruby headers request via ajax call to a different domain

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-grape

So I'm creating an API using ruby's grape with an authentication being sent via http-headers.

my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "some_url.com",
  headers: {"auth": my_auth},
  success: function(data){console.log(data})    
})
```

my grape API::Root < Grape::API

```
....
before do
  puts "Hello World"
  header['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'         
  header['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "*"
end
```

interestingly is my ajax call works, if i send it without its headers-property.
I've also tried using the beforeSend with request.setRequestHeader but it still doesn't work. however when I attached the headers-property, not even the "Hello World" seen in the console.

it was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's JavaScript console to see if there is an error message reported there?

Comment: Ah yeah, crap, I didn't notice that with header attached on the message, it would make an OPTIONS requests to that "some_url.com" first which wasn't handled.

so yeah, what I did is simply add a routing for options "[.*]" which handle anything, but did nothing anyway.

not sure what's the best practice for this though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable CORS in your application.

You can use rake-cors gem (https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

You can take a look about how to use with grape here: https://github.com/intridea/grape#cors